# golang tool to check json file format

Tags: json, go

Is there a tool like `gofmt` to check the format of JSON files in a go repository?  This would be used as a makefile target and git precommit hook.

I know I could code something using `jq`.  But I bet someone has done this.  Also, I prefer if it's in the go ecosystem, to make installation easier -- so I don't have to figure out how to install jq on all the different development systems that our developers use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) - a Pure Go implementation of `jq`

> This is an implementation of jq command written in Go language. You can also embed gojq as a library to your Go products.

The Project seems to be actively developed and maintained. However I don't know how closely it reimplemented the featureset of, say, jq 1.5.

Comment: Thanks: `gojq` avoids `jq` install issues, though it doesn't work the same way as `gofmt` for a project.  Easily scripted to achieve the effect.